# Relationship Constraints on weighted shortest path in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints, shortest-path

I am experimenting with neo4j. 
I have a graph like this.
[image]

The query to create the above graph:

```
merge (:node{name : '1'});
merge (:node{name : '2'});
merge (:node{name : '3'});
merge (:node{name : '4'});
merge (:node{name : '5'});
merge (:node{name : '6'});
merge (:node{name : '7'});
merge (:node{name : '8'});

match (n1:node{name : '1'}), (n2:node{name : '2'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 100, Property1:'P1', Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '2'}), (n2:node{name : '3'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 100, Property1:'P1', Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '3'}), (n2:node{name : '4'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 200, Property1:'P1', Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '1'}), (n2:node{name : '5'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 40, Property1:'P1'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '5'}), (n2:node{name : '6'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 50, Property1:'P1'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '6'}), (n2:node{name : '4'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 60, Property1:'P1'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '1'}), (n2:node{name : '7'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 60, Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '7'}), (n2:node{name : '8'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 60, Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '6'}), (n2:node{name : '8'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 20, Property1:'P1'}]-> (n2)
match (n1:node{name : '8'}), (n2:node{name : '4'}) merge (n1) -[:edge{cost : 20, Property2: 'P2'}]-> (n2)
```

I want the answer to the following queries.

1. Shortest path between 1 to 4 where relationship property : Property1 = 'P1' and relationship property : Property2 = 'P2' ( Cost : 400, 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4)
2. Shortest path between 1 to 4 where relationship property : Property1 = 'P1' (Cost : 150, 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 4). Here the path (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4) is also valid, but since its cost is large, it is not the answer.
3. Shortest path between 1 to 4 where relationship property : Property2 = 'P2' (Cost : 140, 1 -> 7 -> 8 -> 4). Again here the path (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4) is also valid, but since its cost is large, it is not the answer.
4. Shortest path between 1 to 4 where relationship property : Property1 = 'P1' or relationship property : Property2 = 'P2' ( Cost : 130, 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 4). Here any path is valid, but the above path is the optimal.
5. Shortest path between 1 to 4 where relationship property : Property1 != 'P1'. (Cost : 140, 1 -> 7 -> 8 -> 4).

Here, Property1 can be anything and Property2 also can be anything (not necessarily 'P1' and 'P2' respectively.). In all cases, if there is an edge whose relationship property Property1 = 'P3', then that edge should be considered for optimal path.

Suppose if I want to filter based on the node condition too (like node having Property = 'P5') along with relationship condition, can this be done ?

Am using cypher query language.

A good search on the internet gives only giving constraints on non weighted graph ([Cypher: Shortest Path with Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631953/cypher-shortest-path-with-constraint))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the graph algorithms library. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/shortest-path/

```
//1.
MATCH (start:node {name: '1'}), (end:node {name: '4'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost', {
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (n:node) RETURN id(n) as id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:node)-[r:edge]->(m:node) WHERE r.Property1="P1" and r.Property2="P2" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS weight',
    graph: 'cypher', duplicateRelationships: 'min'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost;

//2.
MATCH (start:node {name: '1'}), (end:node {name: '4'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost', {
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (n:node) RETURN id(n) as id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:node)-[r:edge]->(m:node) WHERE r.Property1="P1" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS weight',
    graph: 'cypher', duplicateRelationships: 'min'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost;

//3.
MATCH (start:node {name: '1'}), (end:node {name: '4'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost', {
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (n:node) RETURN id(n) as id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:node)-[r:edge]->(m:node) WHERE r.Property2="P2" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS weight',
    graph: 'cypher', duplicateRelationships: 'min'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost;

//4.
MATCH (start:node {name: '1'}), (end:node {name: '4'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost', {
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (n:node) RETURN id(n) as id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:node)-[r:edge]->(m:node) WHERE r.Property1="P1" or r.Property2 = "P2" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS weight',
    graph: 'cypher', duplicateRelationships: 'min'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost;

//5.
MATCH (start:node {name: '1'}), (end:node {name: '4'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost', {
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (n:node) RETURN id(n) as id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:node)-[r:edge]->(m:node) WHERE  coalesce(r.Property1, "P2")<>"P1" RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target, r.cost AS weight',
    graph: 'cypher', duplicateRelationships: 'min'})
YIELD nodeId, cost
RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, cost;
```